# Kendo UI Treeview data bind to XML: how does it bind to "id"?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have difficulties understanding the inner workings of the `TreeView` widget. I am referring to the [Kendo code library example](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/treeview/binding-to-xml.aspx), specifically the Ajax loading snippet:

```
//Ajax binding data
public JsonResult Employees(string id)
{            
    XElement element = XElement.Load((Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/employees.xml")));
    IEnumerable<Employee> result;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        //search for id and return it's children
        result = FindByID(id, element.Element("Employee")).Element("items").Elements("Employee").Select(e => ToEmployee(e));
    }
    else
    {
       //return first level nodes
       result = element.Elements("Employee").Select(e => ToEmployee(e)) ;
    }

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
} 

//Find the XML element by Id
private XElement FindByID(string id, XElement element)
{...}

//Convert XML element to Object
private Employee ToEmployee(XElement element)
{
    return new Employee()
    {
       id = int.Parse(element.Element("employeeId").Value),
       name = element.Element("name").Value,
       hasChildren = element.Element("items") != null
    };
}
```

This is the Model used, which corresponds to the actual XML structure:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool hasChildren { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> items { get; set; }
}
```

The View executes the following code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
.Name("ajaxTree")
.DataTextField("name")      
.DataSource(source =>
{
    source.Read(read =>
    {
        read.Action("Employees", "Home");
    });
})
)
```

What bothers me is the fact that the Model needs to be implemented exactly as in this example. Specifically, the "id" and "hasChildren" properties need to be specified exactly in this manner. Modifying, for example, "id" into "Id" would render this example ineffective and the `TreeView` would not load. Can somebody help me with the following?

1. How is the binding actually accomplished?
2. Why must I design my model with lower-case properties? (I know it sound weird, but it conflicts with the rest of my (group) project's formatting...)
3. Is there a way to bind the Kendo required "id" and "hasChildren" to other properties (same function, different name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you got an answer for your question.

This link http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/remote-data.html will help you understand how your model data is bound to treeview. Please go through below links.

1. HierarchicalDataSource - http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/hierarchicaldatasource
2. DataSource - http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource
3. Model - http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model

For question #2, #3

Yes, it is possible to configure your model properties as below:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "EmployeeId",
        hasChildren: "HasEmployees",
        children: "EmployeeArray"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer cleared up some things. I did read prior to posting the documentation. I guess my confusion came from the fact that in the examples I've seen, the BindTo() method was used on local data. Is it possible to use BindTo() on the data returned by the Controller Action and not trough the ViewBag? Something like `.BindTo(DataSource("read data"), schema...)`. I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: I don't have access to kendo's server side extensions, but you want to use action method for which you need to configure DataSource to read from action. Your original code is already doing that. Not sure what is preventing you to use that code instead of BindTo method.